# Android replace data in HTML

Tags: android, html, xml

I have some data I have parsed from a XML file. `OnClick` of each item I want to show the data parsed in a webview, so how would I replace data out of the webview by tag, i.e html tag %titlt% is replaced with title etc?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear. Can you give more detail (about the webview, items, tags, etc).

Comment: Well tags are stored in a string so just replace HTML tags with the string really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use String.format() but it's positional only
- [TextUtils replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) also positional only
- use a templating library: [Open Source Template Engines in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines)

for something like 3-4 fields I suggest String.format